# Three monitors with two different Nvidia cards

Tags: debian, nvidia

I have a Geforce 460 SE and a Geforce 6600 GT.

OS is Debian 8, current video driver is 340.65.

I'm trying to drive three screens with two cards, two outputs from the 460 and one output from the 6600.

A year or so ago I was able to run three monitors off these two cards, even getting OpenGL acceleration across all three screens. (I did have the run the games in windowed mode and manually specify the resolution, but it worked)

The issue I am having is that the 6600 isn't showing up in the "nvidia-settings" tool, but it shows up in lspci.

My guess as to what happened is that I upgraded drivers somewhere along the line, and nvidia support for the 6600 was dropped. I tried selecting the card I have on the nvidia driver site and I see "352.30" for the 460 and "304.125" for the 6600. If this is the case than this is incredibly stupid and frustrating, I have good hardware and I am losing features by upgrading my software!

My questions:

1. Do I need to downgrade my video driver in order to get three monitor support back?
2. Should I try the open source video driver? Or is performance not enough to be able to play games like TF2?
3. Is there a way I can switch between 340.65 and 304.125 drivers without having to reboot? I have a screen session running with a ton of open applications and I would rather not interrupt my current work in progress. I know that I'll have to shutdown x.org but that shouldn't be an issue. Pretty sure there is a kernel module that gets compiled as well, but shouldn't have to reboot to insert and remove a kernel module...

Thanks!